# python insert not inserting at the correct position

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing

I am trying to use python's insert to find the palindrome of a number. This is my function:

```
def isPalindrome(x):
        n = []
        l = len(str(x)) - 1
        for i in str(x):
            print(l, ":", i)
            n.insert(l,i)
            l -= 1
        print(n)
```

Output for the number 121:

```
2 : 1
1 : 2
0 : 1
['1', '1', '2']
```

I printed out what the index,value combo should be... so how  come the printed array says ['1', '1', '2'], instead of the expected ['1', '2', '1']?

Comment: Are you trying to find the palindrome if a specific string? you could try this `print("121"[::-1])`

Comment: Yeah, thank you! but I'm still wondering why my insert method is not inserting the numbers at the correct index.

Comment: Ohh okay but also if you'd like to have the string in a list in my example you could try this `output = [s for s in "ana"[::-1]]`   . Hmmm... Okay okay

Comment: could you change to `n.append(i)` cause what `.insert()` does is `inserting` your value of `i` to the location `l` and whatever it's value is.

Answer (score 1):

`list.insert()` will not create positions in the list for you.  It will insert at the end instead.  You are trying to insert something into position 2 of an empty list.  It will instead append to the list, so the insertion is actually into position 0.

```
>>> l = []
>>> l.insert(2, "X")
>>> l
['X']
```

Answer (score 0):

You created an empty array n with a length of zero. Then you try to insert the first digit '1' at position 2, which does not exist in an empty array. Then you place the second digit '2' at position 1 (the end of the array). Then the last digit '1' at position 0 (the beginning of the array).

```
[], ['1'], ['1','2'], ['1','1','2']
```

If you are trying to create an array of digits in reverse order. You need to add the each digit to the beginning of the array.

```
n.insert(0, i)
```

Inserts the first digit '1' at position 0 ['1'], then second digit at 0 ['2','1'], then last digit at the beginning ['1','2','1']. Or you could could just use this function.

```
def isPalindrome(s):
    s = str(s)
    return s == s[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set l = 0 at the beginning of your function so you push elements from the beginning rather than the end.